# Fabric8 Maven plugin configuration to enable HTTPS / TLS route in Openshift

Tags: maven, spring-boot, openshift, fabric8

Is there a way to configure an Openshift route linked to a service created with a fabric8-maven-plugin ?

With the zero-config a route is created but how to configure it to add an edge TLS termination ? I cannot find an element in XML configuration to setup it :( Is there a fragment to configure the route ?
Is there something we can do with expose-controller ?

Answer (score 0):

We can add a route description in src/main/fabric8/route.yml, here is a sample :

```
metadata:
  name: myRoute
spec:
  host: myhost.mydomain.com
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: myService
  tls:
    termination: edge
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimum file possible (in src/main/fabric8/route.yml) :

```
spec:
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: myService
  tls:
    termination: edge
```